# Abstract algebra, polynomials , division.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

It says here that $S,T$ are polynomials and $S=0, T \neq 0$ then $GCD(S,T)=a^{-1}T$ where $a$is the leading coefficient of polynomial $T$. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the convention here is that the gcd is monic. Given that, we know that everything divides 0, so the only real constraint on the gcd is that it must divide $T$. $a^{-1}T$ divides $T$ (and 0), and anything that divides $T$  (and 0) divides $a^{-1}T$, and the leading coefficient of $a^{-1}T$ is 1, so it must be the gcd.